# Ubuntu Server 22.04 and 20.04 error during installation and stuck on boot

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, system-installation, 22.04

So, I've been trying to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 and 20.04 on an old PC's 250GB HDD (HP MultiSeat ms6200 SFF PC: Intel Pentium G630, 8GB RAM). I've tried to install the OS in two ways:

1. Let the PC boot normally into the OS installer (on a 16GB USB drive). The installation has failed everytime; "Error occured during installation".
2. Boot into the OS installer USB drive through boot menu (legacy boot sources → usb drive). The installation doesn't fail that way, but after completion and restart it gets stuck on the "loading text" right before login.

Has anyone had similar issues and does anyone know how this could be fixed? Also, I have an i5-2400, which I could try on the PC.

edit: tried with the i5-2400. Same issues with that one...

edit: got it installed!

Comment: Mind sharing what did you do? Getting some problem on a Dell T20

Comment: @jcalonso The second method (legacy boot) did work. At first I thought that it got stuck and didn't work but it never actually got stuck on anything and works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up legacy booting and also disconnecting other disks I had with linux partitions